# AQuery - Item position in listview is wrong

Tags: android, android-listview, android-query

I wrote a custom ArrayAdapter to show my listview items.

My items have many types. if the type is text then i show a TextView and if the type is Image or Video i show an ImageView (for video the thumbnail).

This is the code.

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NMessage> {
public static final int ALL_MESSAGES = 0;
public static final int MEDIA_ONLY = 1;
Context context;
DatabaseActions db;
ArrayList<NMessage> items;
AQuery aq;
Profile myProfile = ProfilesSingleton.getInstance().getCurrentProfile();
LayoutInflater inflater;
int type;

public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<NMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    items = objects;
    aq = new AQuery(context);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.type = type;
    db = new DatabaseActions();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    final NMessage msg = items.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (row == null) {
        if (type == 1) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.out_message, parent, false);
        } else if (type == 0) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.in_message, parent, false);
        }

        holder.avatar = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        holder.profileName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
        holder.text = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msg_body);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image_message);
        holder.video = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.video_message);
        holder.time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msg_date);
        holder.location = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.location_message);
        holder.audioController = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.audioContainer);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.audioController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.location.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    AQuery rowAq = aq.recycle(row);
    holder.text.setText(msg.getText());
    holder.time.setText(Util.dateParser((Long.parseLong(msg.getTime()))));

    if(!msg.isSent()) {
        rowAq.id(holder.avatar).image(Util.URL_USERS_PHOTOS+msg.getPhoto_path(), false, true, 50, R.drawable.avatar_profile);
        holder.profileName.setText(msg.getName());
    } else {
        rowAq.id(holder.avatar).image(myProfile.getFullPhotoPath(), false, true, 50, R.drawable.avatar_profile);
        holder.profileName.setText("you");
    }


    switch (msg.getType()){
        case NMessage.TEXT:
            holder.text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case NMessage.IMAGE:
            rowAq.id(holder.image).image(msg.getText(), false, true, 100, R.drawable.ic_photo).visible();
            break;
        case NMessage.VIDEO:
            String url = msg.getText().replace(msg.getText().substring(msg.getText().lastIndexOf(".")), ".jpg");
            rowAq.id(holder.video).image(url, false, true, 100, R.drawable.ic_video).visible();
            break;
        case NMessage.LOCATION:
            holder.location.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case NMessage.AUDIO:
            holder.audioController.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }

    return row;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    NMessage message = items.get(position);
    if (message.isSent()) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    MediaController controller;
    RelativeLayout audioController;
    ImageView avatar,
            image,
            video,
            location;
    TextView text;
    TextView time;
    TextView profileName;
}
}
```

The problem is that some views are not shown in the right place. when i scroll the listview and scroll back they are arranged properly.

This is before i scroll. (when the listview is first populated)
[image]

This is after i scroll and scroll back. the imageview is gone and the right type (text) is shown.
[image]

I searched everywhere but cannot seem to find the answer even in AQuery's wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

As the [this blog post](http://sparetimedev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/recycling-of-views-with-heterogeneous.html) explains, Android does not actually guarantee that getView will receive the correct type of view.

Comment: then what should i do to make my list views look ok?!

Comment: It's not easy to say for me. code needs review and debug.